# How to simplify the long equation?

Tags: excel

So basically, I have 3 arrays of numbers. ONe from B8:E14, B21:E27, and H21:K27. I have this ridiculously long equation in order to find the answer I am looking for:

=(B8*(B21+H21))+(C8*(C21+I21))+(D8*(D21+J21))+(E8*(E21+K21))+(B9*(B22+H22))+(C9*(C22+I22))+(D9*(D22+J22))+(E9*(E22+K22))+(B10*(B23+H23))+(C10*(C23+I23))+(D10*(D23+J23))+(E10*(E23+K23))+(B11*(B24+H24))+(C11*(C24+I24))+(D11*(D24+J24))+(E11*(E24+K24))+(B12*(B25+H25))+(C12*(C25+I25))+(D12*(D25+J25))+(E12*(E25+K25))+(B13*(B26+H26))+(C13*(C26+I26))+(D13*(D26+J26))+(E13*E26+K26))+(B14*(B27+H27))+(C14*(C27+I27))+(D14*(D27+J27))+(E14*(E27+K27))

Excel won't even accept this as an equation and I'm not sure why. I think I can use SumProduct in some way here but I can't figure out how, it keeps giving me the wrong answer. I hope I have included enough information here. Please let me know if there is anything I should add. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a symbolic or mathematical formula on hand? What calculation are you trying to do and what does your dataset look like?

Comment: You have a typo in "(E13*E26+K26))" - missing opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be to use an array formula:

```
=SUM(B8:E14*(B21:E27+H21:K27))
```

Type (or copy & paste) the above formula into some cell, and then click ctrl-shift-enter to create an array formula.